# How to Center background in Andengine Scene

Tags: java, android, andengine

Is there a formula to use to center a background in the camera of Andengine.

My camera is the size of the Screen on the particular device which i retrieve using this...

```
final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
CAMERA_WIDTH = display.getWidth(); 
CAMERA_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();

int x = //formula to center background in camera or screen on the X axis

int y = //formula to center background in camera or screen on the Y axis
```

For my SpriteBackground, how could i figure out what is the x, and y to center it in the camera?

The x and y is supplied like this..

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(x,y,TextureRegion);
```

Comment: what is Sprite? and what are the parameters it take?

Comment: Its in my question Sprite sprite = new Sprite(int,int TextureRegion); I just need the X, and Y to center it in the scene using the screens height and width.

Comment: I meant the int int are what? top and left?

Comment: Oh X is horizontal, Y is vertical in landscape.

Comment: 0 starts furthest to the left for x, and 0 for y starts at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final float x = CAMERA_WIDTH / 2 - textureRegion.getWidth() / 2;
final float y = CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2 - textureRegion.getHeight() / 2;
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(x, y, textureRegion);
```

This will make sprite positioned in the middle of the scene. If the camera doesn't move around, it will be the center of the camera (hence screen) too.

Answer (score 1):

You should check setBackground method for your scene. It will center your sprite and move it when your camera moves.

```
    Sprite background = new Sprite(0,0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, backgroundTextureRegion);
    scene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(background));
```